# Ceilometer group by metadata

Tags: filter, metadata, openstack, ceilometer

With ceilometer statistics, is possible filter by grouby with resource_metadata? For example, with instance, group by flavor.name from metadata.

ceilometer statistics -m instance -g resource_metadata[any field]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you attach metadata with the prefix of `metering.` to an instance (eg: `metering.some_name`)

```
$ nova show <instance_id>
...
| metadata | {"metering.some_name": "some_value"} | 
...
```

Then you can get Ceilometer to aggregate samples and calculate statistics across all instances with the `metering.somename` metadata that has `some_value` by using a query of the form:

```
-q metadata.user_metadata.some_name=some_value
```

eg:

```
ceilometer sample-list -m cpu_util -q metadata.user_metadata.some_name=some_value

ceilometer statistics -m cpu_util -q metadata.user_metadata.some_name=some_value -p 60 -a avg
```